# Hibernate Mapping Only one class

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hibernate Mapping
How to implement such a code?

Each company has two properties, they are company name and estimated annual earnings.
There are two types of companies: 1- Main company, 2 - Subsidiary company.
The company can belong only to one company but can have a few child companies.

```
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String companyName;
    private double estimatedAnnualEarnings;

    private Company company; // here need to do a @OneToOne

    private List<Company> subsidiaryCompany; // here need to do a @OneToMany
}
```

Comment: First of all where's the `@Entity` in your class?! And have you tried something? Show it. What errors do you get?

Comment: How to implement such code - simple, take the code - here you go its implemented

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you exactly wanted to do?

Comment: Each company has two properties, they are company name and estimated annual earnings.
There are two types of companies: 1- Main company, 2 - Subsidiary company.
The company can belong only to one company but can have a few child companies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Implementation you should use :

- The `@Entity` annotation in your class level, so the entity can be persisted to database.
- The `@Column` annotation with the `companyName` and `estimatedAnnualEarnings` properties, so they can be persisted as columns in the database.
- `@ManyToOne` annotation with the `company` field, so it can be mapped with a self-reference relationship.
- The same goes with the `subsidiaryCompany` List which needs to be mapped with `@OneToMany` annotation to have a relationship too.

This is how should be your code:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String companyName;

    @Column
    private double estimatedAnnualEarnings;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="mainCompanyId")
    private Company mainCompany; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mainCompany")
    private List<Company> subsidiaryCompanies; 

    //getters and setters goes here
}
```

**Note**

- I changed the name of `company` field to `mainCompany` and
  `subsidiaryCompaniy` to `subsidiaryCompanies` for better readability
  and to make it fit the logic better.
- If you want to give your entity a different name in the database you
  should use `@Table(name="differentName")` in the class level with
  `@Entity` annotation, the smae thing with the columns you can add
  `name` property to the `@Column` annotation i.e
  `@Column(name="company_name")` if you want different names.